# Cursor Select statement Where condition changes based on condition

Tags: oracle, select, cursor, conditional-statements

I am using a Cursor in a procedure, here I am not using Bulk collect since I have lot of calculations on the records fetched from Cursor.

In Cursor's Select statement Where clause changes based on condition , I am trying to use the code as below but it is giving me error:

Error(19,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "c_recs" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE        "test" 
  (fromdate_in               IN varchar2,
     todate_in               IN varchar2,
     atype_in                IN number
    )
 is

 begin
  if atype_in = 01 then  
    cursor c_recs IS SELECT cname FROM A_AUD AA WHERE AA.atime BETWEEN to_date( '' || fromdate_in || '' ,'DD/MM/RRRR')
    AND to_date('' || todate_in || '','DD/MM/RRRR') AND AA.CTYPE IN ('RAlert');
 elsif  atype_in = 02
   cursor c_auditrecs IS  SELECT cname FROM A_AUD AA WHERE AA.atime BETWEEN to_date( '' || fromdate_in || '' ,'DD/MM/RRRR')
    AND to_date('' || todate_in || '','DD/MM/RRRR') AND AA.CTYPE IN ('DAlert');
 end if;
end


begin
--more logic

 FOR rec IN c_recs LOOP
  ---calculations

 END LOOP;

END test;
```

I do not want to use SYS_REFCURSOR as from net , i read cursors are slight better than ref cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better and efficient  option would be to do it in a single statement without any CURSORs. But, it does depend on what you want to do.If you have to do dmls based on the cursor records, preferably do it in a single statement.

If indeed you want to process something in a loop, use an implicit cursor loop which is equivalent ( and sometimes better performant ) to explicit cursors.

The select query can also be simplified with conditional logic rather than IF/ELSE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "test" (
     fromdate_in   IN VARCHAR2,
     todate_in     IN VARCHAR2,
     atype_in
          in NUMBER
) is begin 

for cur in (
     SELECT cname
     FROM a_aud aa
     WHERE aa.time BETWEEN TO_DATE(fromdate_in,'dd/mm/rrrr') 
     AND TO_DATE(todate_in,'dd/mm/rrrr') AND (
          (
               atype_in = '01' AND aa.ctype = 'RAlert'
          ) OR (
               atype_in = '02' AND aa.ctype = 'DAlert'
          )
     )
) loop
                         ---calculations
    do_something_with(cur.cname)
   end loop;
 end;  
 /
```

I would also suggest you to have the type of arguments as dates and pass the variables directly from the calling block rather than converting them inside the sql/cursor.This will avoid `TO_DATE` conversion.

Comment: Thanks Nayak, I used this solution

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` in cursor declaration solves that problem:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c_recs
   IS
      SELECT cname
        FROM a_aud aa
       WHERE     aa.time BETWEEN TO_DATE (fromdate_in, 'dd/mm/rrrr')
                             AND TO_DATE (todate_in, 'dd/mm/rrrr')
             AND aa.ctype =
                    CASE
                       WHEN atype_in = '01' THEN 'RAlert'
                       WHEN atype_in = '02' THEN 'DAlert'
                    END;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN c_recs
   LOOP
      NULL;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I can't comment your refcursor statement.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, answer was useful